# Who/what makes up the nodes of the testnet?

Tags: testnets

Is the testnet centralized?  Like is there a foundation that maintains the testnet nodes?  Or is it just a lot of people who want to support testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Kovan is a new testnet for Ethereum using **Parity**'s *Proof of Authority consensus* engine": https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal
- Ropsten public testnet with *Proof of Work* consensus: https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten
- Rinkeby is a cross-client *Proof-of-authority* testnet supported by the ethereum foundation: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225

if you go give a look at the config file of geth https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/config.go.

You see:

- at line 34, `chainId is 1` refers to the mainnet
- at line 49, `chainId is 3` refers to ropsten testnet
- at line 64, `chainId is 4` refers to rinkeby testnet

to access kovan, you need the parity client.

Those public testnets are the initiative of the ethereum foundation or the parity team. But everyone is free to join (by that I mean running a mining node to help supporting the testnet). However as the coins (test-ether) on those network do not have any value there is no economic incentive to run a node. So those networks are mainly maintained by the developer teams and some enthusiasts

Comment: "those networks are mainly maintained by the developer teams and some enthusiasts " was the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Follow up question.  Is there a way to find out how many nodes are in each testnet?

Comment: kind of:
rinkeby has a dedicated stats website https://www.rinkeby.io/#stats

otherwise etherscan provides charts for every network. For example for ropsten https://ropsten.etherscan.io/charts

but hey there google should be your friend (what I just did)

Comment: As far as I know, the difficulty to mine blocks is extremely easy in the testnet...